# onPaint fires too many times

Tags: winforms, wcf, winforms-interop

I have a winforms user control which enables users edit workflows upon a panel. A workflow consists of building blocks and wires which are also my usercontrols.

When I migrated the app from a winforms.exe to be a winform control upon another WCF app, I have noticed that CPU usage climbs to 25% (=100% of a single core of my 4 core machine)

CPU drops back at runtime to 0-1% as soon as:

I clear my workflow panel from any existing controls, or

I move screen focus to another app (and leave this to run in the background) or even a different tab in the same app.

It is important to say that this doesn't happen in the Windows forms hosting application, only in WCF.

I seen a place where they override WndProc method of the base workflow block UC and I also did, but still I don't understand what is calling the WndProc method so many times or how to make it stop.

My stack looks something like:

> BaseControls.dll!Ast.Admin.Controls.BaseControl.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m = {System.Windows.Forms.Message}) Line 91    C#
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0x1d bytes
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0xaa bytes
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg = 129, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam) + 0x6f bytes 
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.WindowClass.Callback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam) + 0x51 bytes
>       [Native to Managed Transition]
>       [Managed to Native Transition]
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CreateWindowEx(int dwExStyle, string lpszClassName, string lpszWindowName, int style, int x, int y, int width, int height, System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef hWndParent, System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef hMenu, System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef hInst, object pvParam) + 0x3f bytes
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.CreateHandle(System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams cp) + 0x22d bytes 
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateHandle() + 0x12c bytes
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(bool fIgnoreVisible = false) + 0x89 bytes
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl() + 0x31 bytes
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection.Add(System.Windows.Forms.Control value = {Ast.Controls.AllianceEnterprise.DataSource}) + 0x1dd bytes
>       AdminUC.dll!Ast.Admin.AdminUC.RuleBuilderUC.AddItem(object objData = "C:\Ast Alliance NextUI\Bin\Escalation\Controls\Actions\DataConnector.dll;Ast.Controls.AllianceEnterprise.DataSource") + 0x510 bytes 
>       AdminUC.dll!Ast.Admin.AdminUC.RuleBuilderUC.drawingPanel_DragDrop(object sender = {System.Windows.Forms.Panel}, System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs e = {System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs}) + 0xa0 bytes
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnDragDrop(System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs drgevent) + 0x73 bytes
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.System.Windows.Forms.IDropTarget.OnDragDrop(System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs drgEvent) + 0x15 bytes 
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.DropTarget.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IOleDropTarget.OleDrop(object pDataObj, int grfKeyState, long pt, ref int pdwEffect = 1) + 0x5d bytes 
>       [Native to Managed Transition]
>       [Managed to Native Transition]
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.DoDragDrop(object data, System.Windows.Forms.DragDropEffects allowedEffects) + 0xed bytes 
>       AdminUC.dll!Ast.Admin.AdminUC.RuleBuilderUC.listView_MouseDown(object sender = {System.Windows.Forms.ListView}, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e = {X = 16 Y = 6 Button = Left}) + 0x285 bytes 
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnMouseDown(System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e) + 0x73 bytes
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ListView.WmMouseDown(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m = {System.Windows.Forms.Message}, System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons button, int clicks) + 0x7a bytes
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ListView.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0xf7 bytes 
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0x1d bytes
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0xaa bytes
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg = 513, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam) + 0x6f bytes 
>       [Native to Managed Transition]
>       [Managed to Native Transition]
>       WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame frame = {System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame}) + 0xb5 bytes 
>       WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame frame) + 0x3c bytes
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(object ignore) + 0x34 bytes
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window window) + 0x16f bytes
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window window) + 0x33 bytes 
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.Run() + 0x69 bytes 
>       Ast Browser.exe!Ast.NextUI.GUI.Shell.App.StartApplication() + 0x75 bytes
>       Ast Browser.exe!Ast.NextUI.GUI.Shell.App.Main(string[] args) + 0x22b bytes

where basecontrol is my base class to the workflow blocks.

this continue to happen forever from the second I lay the first block on the pannel, and it is not like I'm doing anything on screen to justify all this paining.

Comment: You are probably not revalidating the window in onPaint.

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work:                                                         protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            int hWnd = this.Handle.ToInt32();
            if (m.Msg == WM_PAINT)
            {
                PAINTSTRUCT ps = new PAINTSTRUCT();
                BeginPaint(hWnd, ref ps);
                EndPaint(hWnd, ref ps);
            }
            else
            {
                base.WndProc(ref m);
            }

Comment: You need to place a breakpoint in WM_PAINT like so: `if(rand()%1000=0)DebugBreak();` this will break roughly every 1000 redraws. Then examine the call stack to see where it is coming from. WM_PAINT may be sent syncrhonously in response to application code or asynchronously in idle time in response to invalid regions in the window (the classic case). When you establish which it is you can carry on from there.

Comment: I think you mean WPF, not WCF

Answer (score 0):

What is this doing in there:

```
[Managed to Native Transition]
 System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CreateWindowEx(int dwExStyle, string lpszClassName, string lpszWindowName, int style, int x, int y, int width, int height, System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef hWndParent, System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef hMenu, System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef hInst, object pvParam) + 0x3f bytes
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.CreateHandle(System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams cp) + 0x22d bytes 
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateHandle() + 0x12c bytes
```

It looks like OnPaint is being called because the window is being created for the first time.

If this is a *typical* call stack, being called hundreds of times per second during a drag-and-drop application, you really need to find out why and stop it...